# rsync command with sane defaults to backup to an external NTFS hard drive?

Tags: backup, ntfs, rsync

For compatibility reasons, I formatted my external hard drive with NTFS. I would like to use this drive to backup my entire Linux home folder. Given all the configurations and parameters that rsync provides, which command is recommended to achieve this operation?

Comment: Is your NTFS drive configured to use POSIX permissions and ownership?

Comment: Very good question! How can I find it out?

Comment: If you only want to open the backup in Linux, you also could create a big file in Linux and format that with e.g. ext4 and mount it as loop device. It also should be possible to use qemu container images. Backup up a Unix filesystem to NTFS will lead to problems sooner or later.

Comment: I chose rsync because I want to have direct access to my files on my external drive without having to install any other tool.

Comment: Not a good choice if you care about permissions.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/514870/158442